# Issue with Stack Overflow Jobs page on Chrome for Android

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

While surfing Stack Overflow Jobs on Android device using Chrome Browser, if I scroll to the bottom of the page, the whole page turns blank (white) and no actions are available. I have to manually reload the page again to see the content.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open Stack Overflow Jobs
2. Click on any Job Post
3. Scroll down to the bottom of the screen.

**Browser Details (User-Agent) are:**

`Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; Moto G (5S) Plus) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Mobile Safari/537.36`

Comment: Also happens on Firefox Preview and Chrome Beta on Android.

Comment: No repro on chrome on android.

Comment: Can reproduce with Chrome for Android version 81.0.4044.138 and Kiwi Browser Quadea.

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks for the report. Looks like it's not an Android-specific bug, it even happens on desktop when browsing the mobile site.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the bug report! There was a JS bug related to the similar jobs section at the bottom of the page. Should be fixed now.